# HDP MapReduce Jobs Concurrency

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, sqoop, ambari, hdp

I am trying to import data from Oracle to internal Hive with sqoop. My sqoop queries work fine but when I try to run multiple sqoop queries at the same time in a script, just one MapReduce job's running and the others are waiting on the accepted queue on YARN. The tables that I try to import with sqoop approximately have ~500 million lines and ~100 columns. I did some changes in services configuration but the problem is still.

Is there any way to run these MapReduce jobs concurrently? My cluster information mentioned below.

HDP 3.0.1, Ambari 2.7.0,
4 master nodes, 3 utility nodes, 7 worker nodes. Each node has 128 GB Memory and 32 CPUs.
Sqoop version is 1.4.7. Thanks.
[image: YARN Confugiration-1]

[image: YARN Configuration-2]

[image: MapReduce Confugiration]

[image: HDFS Configuration]

[image: YARN Application Queue]

Answer (score 0):

yarnsite.xml needs to be adjusted to use a different scheduling policy. I believe FIFO is selected by default.

In the past, this is the web page I used for setting up a Capacity Scheduler. I think you may want to use the Fair Scheduler, but the choice is ultimately yours.
http://www.corejavaguru.com/bigdata/hadoop-tutorial/yarn-scheduler

Note:
you may need to add additional configuration arguments when you submit your job. For example in the capacity scheduler you'll need to define what queue your job should be added too.